# Expected distance of a point from the center of a circle

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, geometry

Given a point "inside" the circle, or "on the circumference" of a circle, how do we calculate the expected distance between that point and the center of the circle?

I read that using integration we can show it is 2R/3 where R is the radius of the circle. But, I'm not sure how to arrive at this answer. Could someone tell me which formula to use and how to go about proving this? I am not a core-mathematics student, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What probability distribution is assumed ? ( I is pretty obvious but do you know ? )

Comment: Let divide disk into annuli. Let some annulus has radius $r$ and thickness $dr$. Then area of this annulus is $2\pi r \, dr$. Total area of disk is $\pi R^2$, then at uniform distribution probability that random point will lie in this annulus is $p(r)=\frac{2\pi r\, dr}{\pi R^2}=\frac{2}{R^2} r\, dr$. $E(r)=\sum r p(r)=$ $\int_0^R r \frac{2}{R^2} r\, dr=$ $\frac{2}{R^2} \int_0^R r^2\, dr=$ $\frac{2}{R^2} \frac{R^3}{3}=\frac{2R}{3}$.